# SSO with Azure active directory for cloud application

Tags: laravel, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

We are an enterprise SaaS software and our customers require an SSO integration with Azure AD. We have therefor developed an SAML enabled app. We now want to publish ourselves in Azure AD app gallery.
We have followed all steps here & connecting blogs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app
And filled/ticked all required fields
But there is no option for publish app or start sp initiated sso.
Can someone guide me to correct way?

Answer (score 0):

To get the app listed in the gallery, you need to follow the instructions on this page - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/howto-app-gallery-listing
The page you linked to is for creating an app registration in a specific tenant.

Comment: Thank you CheifMCFrank,will try the step mention in above document.